# How do you pronounce "xth"?

Tags: pronunciation, ordinal-numbers

I'm wondering how do you pronounce letters when used in place of ordinal numbers.

Examples:

- The *x*th root of five.
- Two to the *y*th power.
- The *i*th odd number.
- The *j*th item on the queue.

I know [how to pronounce *n*th](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/nth), i.e. /ɛnθ/, but I don't think that I can do the same with *x*, *y* or other letters (I find it really hard to pronounce /ɛksθ/). Should I spell x-t-h?

Comment: If you are ever looking for a rhyme for *month*, how about /ɛn plʌs wʌnθ/ ?

Comment: @Henry Shouldn't that be the "en plus first" anway?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Personally, I would say  *n*th, *n* + 1th, *n* + 2th etc.  By contrast, I would say *hundred and first* etc. but I would see those as different formulations

Comment: Should "The xth square root of five." be "The xth root of five"?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: whoops, fixed!

Comment: @Henry—I agree, and my (back-)rationale is that the ordinal quantity is (*n* + 1), *not* just *1*; that is, it's really (*n* + 1)th. And *-th* is the standard suffix—*-st* is an edge case when the ordinal is exactly 1, which it is not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Some native speakers find it difficult to pronounce sixth (  /sɪksθ/ ). It is not uncommon to hear people say 'sikth' (  /sɪkθ/ ). I believe that some are unaware of this mispronunciation.

I personally pronounce 'xth' as /ɛksθ/.

Unfortunately, saying /ɛkθ/ simply sounds wrong so I don't suggest that as an alternative.

If you are reading the expression from a board or a display where the listeners can see it, then you could get away with pronouncing it as /ɛks/. Listeners would tend to fill in the missing sound mentally.  (Edit: Another very good approximation is /ɛkst/ )

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is "x-t-h" blatantly wrong or just uncommon?

Comment: I have never heard 'X.T.H.' spelled out. It sounds wrong to me. Another approximate pronunciation that I would suggest  is /ɛkst/ if you find that possible.

Comment: You should be able to get away with slowing each sound of /ɛksθ/, /ɛk//s//θ/, and then gradually speeding up.

Comment: Note: I have cross-posted the question here http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/pronunciation-of-xth

Comment: Still /kjuθ/ or /dəbljuθ/ sounds funny to me :) I reckon I have to get used to it...

Comment: @HonzaZidek, Those sound absolutely normal to me.  It will be interesting to see what the maths educators say on the other site.

Comment: @hipa, X.T.H. would be very confusing

Comment: The only ones that would actually be difficult to pronounce are *f*th, *h*th, *m*th, *s*th and *x*th. (The "th" is hard to enunciate with *zed*, but easy to produce.) The rest sound weird because they're not "real" words and are unfamiliar outside of the narrow contexts in which their use would be more-or-less mandatory (speaking about mathematics, where an arbitrary member of a sequence need to be named). I'm sure that if the original namers of our letters had known what sort of nonsense we were going to get up to, they'd have given some of them more felicitous names.

Comment: @bye, +1 for castigating the inventors of English. They made a lot of errors such as having day names of different length (e.g. Friday versus Wednesday) and failing to name them in alphabetical order -- a constant annoyance for such people as computer-programmers and questionnaire designers.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I'd rather deal with that than DST, or TimeZones in general. Humans created the idea of measuring time, so why did we have to make it so difficult! I guess the same could be said for a lot of things we humans created, English included.

Answer (score 16):

In India many people pronounce it as /ɛksəθ/. Having a syllable between s and θ helps people say it.

Comment: That seems an excellent idea! I hadn't thought of that. It would certainly be understandable.

Comment: Is that supposed to be IPA?  If so, I can guarantee you that nobody, not even in India, says /eksûth/.

Comment: It should be  /eksəth/. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: I'm still skeptical.  I'd be willing to bet that there aren't any English speakers in existence who pronounce a word-final ⟨th⟩ as /th/.  Pronouncing the first vowel as /e/ also strikes me as highly unusual.

Comment: @Psychonaut I'm guessing that Kushagra was only trying to emphasize the vowel sound between the *x* and *th*, not the rest of the pronunciation. He appears to have incorrectly transcribed the rest of the pronunciation. At a guess, he probably just means /ɛkseθ/ or /ɛksəθ/

Comment: KRyan, that's true. I typed it on my phone where it was not possible to add the IPA symbols. I am extremely sorry if I got people confused.

Comment: I've heard this used in Canada as well. I'm guessing that people in the maths and sciences share such things without thinking about them.